# PHP : Create function and call it from within a foreach

Tags: php, function, foreach

I have this

```
<?php 

foreach ($results as $row):

    if ($row['title'] == "") $row['title'] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['date']));
    if (strlen($row['text']) > 100) $row['text'] = substr($row['text'], 0, 100) . "...";

?>
        <div>
            <a href="<?php echo $row['url'] ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['title'] ?>" />
            <h1><?php echo $row['title'] ?></h1>
            <p><?php echo $row['text']; ?></p>
            </a>
        </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Right after the foreach starts I do some "house cleaning" where I substitute the date if there is no title and reduce the text to 100 characters etc.

Repeating this over and over is not very efficient, so it would be better to create a function right?

My question is how do I do this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Even if you put it in a function the code will still execute the same number of times. Putting it in a function is only helpful if you use the same code somewhere else.

Comment: What does that mean Dagon? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Yotaware that's what I wan't to do. I want to use this function in other places.

Comment: I'm using Codeigniter. Which allows me to define a function and load it globally so all my scripts have access to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try rewriting your code like this. Just add more of your required functionality to the processRowData() function.

```
<?php

function processRowData($row) {
    if ($row['title'] == "") {
        $row['title'] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['date']));
    }
    // Do more with other elements from $row ...
    // when done, return the modified $row array
    return $row;
}

?>

<?php

foreach ($results as $row) {
    // Alter the row data with your function
    $row = processRowData($row);
?>

<div>
    <a href="<?php echo $row['url'] ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['title'] ?>" />
    <h1><?php echo $row['title'] ?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $row['text']; ?></p>
    </a>
</div>


<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You can pass variable by reference `processRowData(&$row)` and then you don't have to return it as it would be changed on the fly. Additionally, in mixed html/php its better to use `foreach():` and `endforeach;`, not brackets `{ ... }`, because it's more readable.